# Setting or Changing Display Value of a Lookup Field

Tags: lookup-field

I am trying to make it so that when an Order books in my organization, the original Opportunity can be traced to that Order (or multiple Orders related to a single Opportunity).

I put a Lookup relationship object that we can use to search for the original Opportunity ID in order to connect it. Our organization uses its own ID structure and I have set SF Opportunities to be searchable using this unique and required field. The thing is that the people who view the orders (myself included) want to be able to see the "Opportunity ID" in the lookup field. Instead, the "Name" is displayed after it is connected.

How can I change the final view of this lookup connection so that it displays the Opportunity ID field associated with that Opportunity?
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I'd highly recommend against doing this if you can.  We had to do this with a customer of ours and the number of places that needed to be updated was mind boggling. I don't remember all the details, but think about anywhere the Name field is displayed.  reports/list views/lookups/related lists/search/recent items/etc.  Then there's any widget such as a VF component, LWC, Flow, etc.  While this isn't impossible, there are a lot of places you need to be aware of that will need to be updated.

Comment: Why Not just make a cross object formula field showing the Opp Id. If needed you can also use this Id in other formula to construct URL to the Opp if you need to click on to go to the Opp. Also I agree with the comment above, do not change SF things like that, instead extend it and add the thing that you need.

Comment: @BorisGichev Thank you for that. It seems like it gets me most of the way there. The only thing is that this formula field does not appear on the page layout! This seems to have been a request to Salesforce for the past 10 years and presumably delivered in Spring '16 according to: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Zpy4AAC
But it seems as if it has not been implemented and I can't find how to get it to show up on the page layout. This would be incredibly useful for visual inspection to make sure that we have selected the correct opportunity when confirming an order!

Comment: So you have issue with showing a formula field on a page layout? This is a pretty straightforward process please check security settings on the field.

Comment: Only on the input page layout, not on the display page. The link I posted shows this issue, but apparently it has not been resolved, as far as I can tell.